# Changing video content type (mime type) in CDN

Tags: 7, media, cdn

I am using media module to save media in CDN. To play videos, we are using jwplayer in Drupal 7. Jwplayer throws error in IE, If video is not of content type [mime type] video/mp4.
I have changed the existing CDN videos mime type from application/octet-stream to video/mp4.

Now whatever mp4 videos are being uploaded/saved to cdn should only be of video/mp4 mime type but when I upload mp4 videos in media module it is saved in CDN with mime type application/octet-stream, How do I change the uploaded mime type [content type] to video/mp4.

How do I change mime type[content type] to video/mp4 in media module, Drupal 7, when mp4 video are being uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer :

1)  "A MIME-TYPE is a server side setting. You can ask your hosting provider to add the MP4 MIME-TYPE for you.

Or, you can add a .htaccess file to the directory where you uploads are stored".

A sample .htaccess file that adds the MP4 MIME-TYPE is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4
</IfModule>"
```

Source : [Need to Change Video Content Type to video/mp4 so it plays in IE](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=420907&#420907)

But this did not work for me for some reason

2) I did the change in my core class file which i was using in drupal module for CDN upload 
I had made a change in my class.s3.php file -> in mime_type[] array and also, cross checked with putObject() function.

**

> Setting of mime type is always done in coding side and not in AWS S3
>   bucket, We need to use AWS PHP Class file or sdk to do the
>   manipulation in mime type or make the necessary changes in core class
>   file (eg. class.s3.php )

**
 For details check here [find-mime-type-of-file-or-url-using-php-for-all-file-format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22014074/1877909)

Second Answer has worked for me :)